# Deploying issue in Magento -2

Tags: magento2, cache, deploy

I have a js file. Everytime I change something I need to execute the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL
```

`nl_NL` it's my case. Is there a way to avoid this ? cuz it is very frustrating :).

Comment: Development or production website?

Comment: production, but if I enable development mode it is so much slow.

Answer (score 0):

go to your js file from pub/static/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/......

and open your file, edit and save after that just delete the browser cache only... using(ctrl+shift+del) then press ctrl+f5. it will reflect your changes without doing setup:static-content...bla..bla

(note: if your changes set to be finalized then copy that js file from pub/static/.... and paste int your theme directory like app/design/frontend.... )

Comment: in my case there is a checkout JS . I tried your idea , but I still got the old version of js in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the path to the file found in your network tab to make sure you are editing the correct file.

[image: console network tab]

This way you can be sure that you are editing the correct file. To agree with Ashik, I always do my de-bugging in the JS file that is served to the browser while working through a feature or a problem. But be sure to copy the work you do over to the file in your theme. When you run your `deploy` commands, any work in the `pub/static/` folders will be lost.

Doing any file edits in production mode is going to be unreliable. I understand that M2 is very slow compared to some other systems, but it's really just to cost of the framework. I hate to say, but i don't think there is a predictable workflow for developing on production mode.

One idea comes from Alan Storm:

http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/157532793795/magento-2-redis-for-development

He is using redis to speed things up while developing.